# Java ArrayList, I don't know what an IndexOutOfBoundsException is

Tags: java, arraylist

This is the code and add numbers and remove if the par1 or par2 is even.
and give me this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUxPW.png)

```
ArrayList<Integer> s;
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner sm=new Scanner(System.in);
s= new ArrayList<>();
int dorinta=sc.nextInt();
if(dorinta ==1)
    {int numere =sm.nextInt();
    for(int i=0;i<numere;i++)
    {
        Integer x=sc.nextInt();
        s.add(x);
    }
}
Random random = new Random();
while(s.size()!=0)
{int i=s.size();
    int par1 = random.nextInt(20);

    System.out.println(par1);

    if(par1 % 2==0)
    {
       s.remove(s.size());
    }
    int par2= random.nextInt(20);

    Integer j= random.nextInt(15);

    System.out.println(par2);
    if(par2 %2 ==0)
    {
        s.add(j);
    }

    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Comment: it means that you are attempting to get the 7th element of a list that only contains 6 elements.

Comment: `s.remove(s.size());` will always throw that exception. Arrays and lists in Java are 0-indexed.

Comment: @Stultuske is right, but more generally, it means, that you are trying to access an index of the list that does not exist. e.g. index 6 does not exist, if the length of the list is 6, because the list starts at index `0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @QBrute pointed, array and Lists are zero-indexed. That means the first element is at the zeroth index and last element at index (size()-1). Also you need to check if list is empty before removing elements.

Comment: Thank you guys for the responses were truly helpful!